# Errors Compiling Prefix.pch file, Causing bigger problems

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, prefix, pch

**Update 2**

I discovered that if I change the "Base SDK" to "iOS Simulator 3.2" (iPad ???) it does not give me this error when doing Build & Analyze... But this is supposed to be an iPhone App. I am running XCode 3.2.4... am I missing something when I create the Project? I am choosing iPhone as the target device, not sure what's going on.

**Original**

I am having problems finding a memory leak in my iPhone App. I tried running "Build & Analyze", but when it gets to the MyApp_Prefix.pch file, it says "Analyzer skipped this file due to parse errors" - then 50% of the files after that say "Skipped this file due to parse errors - /var/folders/ ... /MyApp_Prefix.pch file not found".

The App actually compiles and runs, and the Prefix.pch file does exist.

When I open all the errors that appear under the first error, it starts opening files that are in the frameworks, which I don't know why there would be something wrong in there.

[image]

Here is the contents of the .pch file:

```
//
// Prefix header for all source files of the 'Tickets' target in the 'Tickets' project
//

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

**UPDATE**
Here are the files that open when I click the 'expected function body after function declarator', 'expected type', etc...
CGPDFContext.h
UIView.h
UIApplication.h
UITextView.h
UIWebView.h

These are all located in the Frameworks.

I tried creating an entirely new project and importing my existing classes, and it gave me the same errors.

I tried running Build & Analyze on one of my older projects, which use the same Frameworks, and it runs fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the exact same problem. I switched from simulator to device and ran "Build & Analyze" again, and lo and behold, it worked. Don't ask me why, but at least this enables you to use the analyze feature.

Comment: I am guessing it might be a bug in the way the current version of XCode creates projects because it works fine on projects that I created with older versions of XCode.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed my build with the following - there seems to be a bug in the current version of XCode so the flag isn't set properly:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
  #ifndef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
    #define __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED __IPHONE_3_0
  #endif

  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

Comment: works for me with one project under XCode5.0, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a peek in the .pch file, its actually a text file with includes/imports. Maybe there is some garbage in there.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything out of the ordinary in the .pch file, it looks like the .pch file that I have in other projects. Added to my original post.